# Node JS server on RPI stops responding when not in use for a while

Tags: web-server, node.js

I'm running a Node JS server on an RPI.
The Node server is handled by PM2.

It works fine... unless it's been sitting around waiting for hours / days, and then it either responds after a long delay (30 secs to 1 minute) or not at all (the browser making the request times out).

I've read in other posts "RPIs don't go to sleep" & "It's a problem with the server code"...

But the node server does seem to "wake up" and work fine after, say, an SSH log in.  In fact you don't even need to log in via SSH.  Just trying to log in and quitting before entering the password is enough to get the Node server become responsive again.

That suggests something about the RPI is "going to sleep" or slowing down, and it wakes up if it gets a nudge.

Comment: Have you inspected the pm2 logs to see if there are server errors, like stop the listening mode? What technology is your server based on? Express? Do you use a mddleware, that could go into sleep mode? Do you use a standard rasbian setup, or something special that might be able to pause the socket and react on (W)LAN connections? Which port does your server use? All ports below 1000 are priviledged and might be able to activate kernel artifacts like sockets. Like port 22 (used for ssh) p80 might be able to wake up the network, while p3000 is not. That's a really rough guess, I admit. ;-)

Comment: If you use a raspbian with pure systemd you have the journalctl command. `journalctl -b' shows you the systemlog from the last boot til now. Perhaps you find something interesting. If you have an old init.d installation. You find the system log files under `/var/log/syslog`.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer Thanks for your insights.  Very helpful.  The port is above 8000.  I may actually have to update my question.  It's turning out that the PI is also not waking up for SSH requests.  More precisely, it doesn't respond to a first SSH request, but does respond to a second.  Or you can make a first request to the HTTP server on 8000 which will not respond, but a followup SSH request will, at which point the HTTP server works fine.  The OS is Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster).  Thanks again for your help.  Still following up on all your notes.  Much appreciated.